# First order differential equation integrating factor is $e^{\int\frac{2}{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So i got the first order ode
$$(x^2-1)\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=x$$
I divided both sides by $x^2-1$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2}{x^2-1}xy=\frac{x}{x^2-1}$$
in the form $y' + p(x)y = q(x)$

So that means the integrand is...
$$e^{\int\frac{2}{x^2-1}}$$

But i'm not sure what to do i think the $\int\frac{2}{x^2-1}$ = $-\log{(x-1)}+4\log{(x+1)}$

So it's $$e^{-\log{(x-1)}+4\log{(x+1)}}$$
$$e^{\log{(x-1)^{-1}}+\log{(x+1)^4}}$$
$$\frac{1}{x-1}+(x+1)^4$$

Is this right? and then just multiply both sides by this?

Comment: your p(x) will be $2x/x^{2}- 1$ isn't it ?

Comment: oh that's what i did wrong that's so much easier... So it's more like $e^{log(x^2-1)} = x^2-1$

Comment: Also $e^{\ln A+\ln B}=e^{\ln A}e^{\ln B}=AB$, not $A+B$

Answer (score 1):

your equation $$(x^2 - 1) \frac{dy}{dx} + 2x y = x $$ is an exact differential equation. the reason is it can be written as $$\frac d{dx}\left((x^2 - 1) y\right) = x $$ on integration gives you $$(x^2 - 1)y = \frac12 x^2 + c \to y = \frac{x^2}{2(x^2 - 1)} + \frac c{x^2 - 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have been told to use the the integration factor, but you can make it a lot easier for yourself. Rearrange for $\frac{dy}{dx}$:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x(2y-1)}{x^2-1}.
\end{equation*}
Divide both sides by $2y-1$and integrate with respect to $x$ gives
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}\ln(2y-1)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln (x^2-1)+C
\end{equation*}
where $C$ is a constant. Solving for $y$ gives the result.